# How to resolve "The operation has timed out."?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I'm trying to send email using C# code, email was sent when I send it to single person but it is not getting sent when I send it to multiple persons. and getting an error "The operation has timed out." I'm not getting the reason behind it. Please help to find the reason.

Code:

```
 public string SendEmail(List<string> ToEmailAddresses,string body, string emailSubject)
    {  
        var smtp = new SmtpClient { DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network };

        smtp.Host = "xyz-host-name";

        smtp.Port = 25;

        smtp.EnableSsl = false;

        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserName"], "Rewards and Recognition Team");

        using (var message = new MailMessage() { Subject = emailSubject, Body = body })
        {
            message.From = fromAddress;

            foreach (string email in ToEmailAddresses)
            {
                message.To.Add(email);
            }
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            try
            {
                _logger.Log("EmailService-SendEmail-try");
                smtp.Send(message);
                return "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Log("EmailService-SendEmail-" + ex.Message);
                return "Error";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: post your full code then only we can able to find the error.

Comment: Note that sending email to multiple recipients is not easy job. Many of emails can be rejected as possible spam.

Comment: Try a higher timeout (value in milliseconds) `smtp.Timeout = 30000;`. Are you sure it's port 25 without SSL? That is unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're attempting to do anything which may take some time, it's always best practice to run it in a separate thread or use an asynchronous method.
My recommendation would be to use the `SmtpClient.SendAsync` method. To do this, change:

```
public string SendEmail(List<string> ToEmailAddresses, string body, string emailSubject)
```

to:

```
public async string SendEmail(List<string> ToEmailAddresses, string body, string emailSubject)
```

and include `await smtp.SendAsync(...)` rather than `smtp.Send(...)`. This will allow further execution of the UI thread whilst sending the mail and not make the application grey out with the "*not responding*" message.
To read more about `smtp.SendAsync(...)` including parameters and remarks, take a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx) regarding the method.